# On the number of Reed–Muller codewords with no consecutive ones

Tags: co.combinatorics, coding-theory, boolean-algebras

$\DeclareMathOperator\RM{RM}\DeclareMathOperator\Eval{Eval}$Consider the polynomial ring $\mathbb{F}_2[x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_m]$ and let $f\in \mathbb{F}_2[x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_m]$. Let us now fix a Gray ordering over the binary strings in $\mathbb{F}_2^m$, where a Gray ordering is such that consecutive strings in the ordering differ in exactly one among the $m$ positions. For example, a Gray ordering over binary strings of length $2$ is $00, 01, 11, 10$.

Now, for a binary vector $z = (z_1,z_2,\dotsc,z_m)\in \mathbb{F}_2^m$, we define the vector $\Eval(f) \mathrel{:=} (f(z):z\in \mathbb{F}_2^m)$, where the order of the strings $z\in \mathbb{F}_2^m$ is as per a fixed Gray ordering.

Consider the collection of all such vectors, $\Eval(f)$, defined using polynomials in $m$ variables, with maximum degree $r$. This collection is precisely the Reed–Muller code $\RM(m,r)$. It is easy to see that the dimension of $\RM(m,r)$ is precisely $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^r {m \choose i}$, where a basis consists of all monomials in $m$ variables, of degree at most $r$. For example, $\RM(3,1)$ consists of linear combinations (over $\mathbb{F}_2$) of the vectors in $\{\Eval(1),\Eval(x_1),\Eval(x_2),\Eval(x_3)\}$.

**My question now is**: in the Reed–Muller code $\RM(m,r)$, how many vectors (which are evaluations of multilinear polynomials) have no consecutive ones? Can one point me to literature on techniques to lower bound the number of such vectors? The question assumes importance in the search for linear codes that offer good achievable rates over input-constrained discrete memoryless channels.

P.S.: One idea was to use the Lovasz Local Lemma to bound the probability of the event that a randomly chosen vector in $\RM(m,r)$ has no consecutive ones, by considering smaller events that correspond to the occurrence of consecutive ones in positions $i$ and $i+1$, for $i\in [2^m-1]$. One can see that under a Gray ordering with the first index set to $(0,0,\ldots,0)\in \mathbb{F}_2^m$, the probability of getting consecutive ones in the first two locations is precisely $1/4$. Further, this equals the probability of getting consecutive ones in any other pair of successive indices (under the Gray ordering), as this is equivalent to merely exchanging co-ordinates $x_i$ and $x_j$ for some $i,j,\in [m]$ in the Boolean function $f$ that the evaluation vector corresponds to.

However, I'm unable to get a picture of what the dependency graph of the events looks like, in order for me to apply the Local Lemma ….

Comment: Can you answer this under the standard order?

Comment: No, I haven't been able to. The change of the ordering was to facilitate the use of the Lovasz Local Lemma, in such a manner as to allow the probabilities of the smaller events that I've stated, to all be equal.

Comment: Have you looked at small examples? Does the choice of Gray code affect the answer?

Comment: Sorry for the extremely delayed response, @JyrkiLahtonen. We have now changed the choice of the ordering back to the standard lexicographic ordering, and we have found that we can obtain almost trivial lower bounds on the rate of a subcode with no consecutive ones. Furthermore, using some more insight based on the Plotkin construction of RM codes, and some cutting-edge results on the weight distribution, we have also been able to get non-trivial upper bounds. The upper bounds, however, are heavily reliant on the strength of bounds on the weight distribution. We will publish these soon.

Comment: For those interested, here is a preprint of our work: in particular, Theorem III.2 shows that for $d=1$, which is the no-consecutive-ones constraint, one can identify subcodes of RM codes of rate at least half the rate of the larger RM code. Theorem III.3 provides a non-trivial upper bound on the rate achievable using subcodes, all of whose codewords do not have consecutive ones, of a particular family of RM codes. The preprint is here:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.02035.pdf